# Mysterious Reply-To Header in Apple Mail

Tags: mail.app, email

I send e-mail with Apple Mail from two different accounts - lets call them A and B. Years ago I set the Reply-To header as my A account address (I think to force use of my 'canonical' address), since then I added my B account. Now all of my outgoing e-mail has the Reply-To header set to my A address. This causes considerable confusion to observant correspondents e-mailed through my B account. So, I'd like to fix this.

Here's where the mystery begins. I don't remember how I set the default Reply-To header. I would have thought that I would have used:

`defaults write com.apple.mail UserHeaders ...`

However

`defaults read com.apple.mail UserHeaders`

tells me "The domain/default pair of (com.apple.mail, UserHeaders) does not exist."

Next, I looked at the configuration on our e-mail provider, FastMail, to see if they might be setting a default Reply-To header. but I didn't see anything there.

Then, I tried resetting Apple Mail back to its default state using the instructions in [How to reset mail to factory settings](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5118986?answerId=22302114022#22302114022) on discussions.apple.com. No dice.

And then, the method in [How to Fix Mail App Not Working After macOS Update](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Skwoo8RjHSw). Strike four.

Manually setting the header when I'm writing an e-mail doesn't work. The value I set gets overwritten, by the value for account A.

Where else could the header be set?

Comment: I've also verified that each account is using a distinct outgoing server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So with a bit of help the problem was tracked down to an interaction between SIP (System Integrity Protection), terminal, and Apple Mail.

Here's what was going on:

- Due to SIP the Terminal app did not have access to Mail's defaults file: `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist`
- As a result, the `defaults` program was unable to read the defaults settings that Mail.app was actually using.
- Instead of reporting an error when trying to access the `com.apple.mail.plist` it reported that the "The domain/default pair of (com.apple.mail, UserHeaders) does not exist."

The big clue was that `defaults read com.apple.mail` returned nothing.

The fix was to allow the Terminal.app full disk access in System Preferences (in Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access). Then you restart Terminal.app.

After that `defaults` works as expected and

`defaults delete com.apple.mail User-Headers`

solved the problem – since I didn't have any other User-Headers set.